# Process based on callback value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-callback

I need to get the call back true/false value when the user click ok/cancel in the popup. The same return value should send to the caller button and it has to process accordingly.

For this i wrote a below JS code with recursive function. But ends with infinite loop.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgx3A/30/)

```
<input type="submit" value="Click" onclick="return confirm(true);" id="btnSample" />


    function confirm(clicked, response) {

        if (typeof (response) != "undefined") {
            return response;
        }
        if (clicked == true, typeof(response)=="undefined") {
            jConfirm('are you sure?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {
                // Do something with r 
                if (r) {
                    confirm(true, r);
                }
            });
        }
        return confirm(true);
    }
```

How can I send a callback result back to the caller and continue processing?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to continue the processing in the callback? Callbacks are generally used when you don't know how long something will take to complete.

Comment: first of all `return confirm(true)` `confirm` is default jquery function. do you want to override that function? if not change the function name and `function confirm(clicked, response)` have two parametters but you are passing only one param

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/Pgx3A/31/

Comment: Also, why do you call confirm within the jConfirm callback and at the end of the method?  That would cause overflow.